# Dropbox not calling delegate methods on iPad only

Tags: objective-c, dropbox-api

I'm using dropbox to upload files to a user's Dropbox.
On iPhone it works flawlessly, but on iPad the delegate methods for the `DBRestClientDelegate` are not being called.
I am still using v1.
The code I'm using is

```
- (DBRestClient *)restClient {
    if (!_restClient) {
        _restClient =
        [[DBRestClient alloc] initWithSession:[DBSession sharedSession]];
        _restClient.delegate = self;
    }
    return _restClient;
}

[[self restClient] uploadFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.jpeg",fileName]
                           toPath:@"/"
                    withParentRev:nil
                         fromPath:imagePath];
```

After calling this on the iPhone the delegate method

```
- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)client uploadedFile:(NSString*)destPath from:(NSString*)srcPath
```

is successfully called, allowing me to handle that. On the iPad, however, that, along with the other delegate methods, are not called, **does not** upload the file and does not throw any errors.

Any thoughts are appreciated.
Thanks,
Luke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things that might cause your delegate methods to not be called:

1. Your rest client is `nil` or is being released (e.g., by ARC) prematurely.
2. You're making the call in a background thread that doesn't have a run loop.
3. Your delegate method that should be called back has a typo in it. Unfortunately the SDK doesn't warn you if it can't find a delegate method to call; it just completes without telling anyone.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in response. The problem was that the `NSObject` that I was using for all my share stuff was being released by ARC (diagnosed using 'Zombies' in instruments) as I had no reference to it. I was sending images to it via a class method. I remedied this by creating a `sharedInstance` (singleton) and then sent the images through an instance method's parameters. Bingo.